# Pyspark UDF works unless I call any builtin functions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to implement a pyspark function to perform half-even rounding.  The problem is if I simply return the value passed in, the build works.  If it does anything else, I get an obscure error.  Here is my udf as it works:

```
@udf(returnType=DecimalType())
def round_half_even(number):
  return number
```

I am simply calling the udf in a select on a dataframe, like this:

```
df1 = spark.read...
df1.select(
    df1.COST,
    round_half_even(f.lit(17.45)).alias('V_COST_TOTAL_CALC')
)
```

But this version which actually does rounding fails:

```
@udf(returnType=DecimalType())
def round_half_even(number):
  return round(number, 0)
```

With this error:

```
TypeError: type NoneType doesn't define __round__ method
```

I am pretty new to Python so I don't really know how to track this down.  It seems like the python environment isn't really available, but that should be spark's problem not mine.

EDIT:  I realized after reviewing this question that spark has a bround function which does half-even rounding.  I still need to resolve this because I have several UDFs which all fail for the same reason and this one seems to be the simplest.

UPDATE:
Null checking was indeed what was causing my udf to fail, so I modified it like this (as suggested by Hristo Iliev):

```
@udf(returnType=DecimalType())
def round_half_even(number):
  return round(number, 0) if number is not None else None
```

Which has allowed it to complete, but now all I get are null values in the target, even when passing in literal values as in the example above.  I have verified that there should be literally 100s of thousands of non-null values.

Comment: can you show the `udf` call?

Comment: Your udf fails, because you don't correct for missing (`NULL` in SQL, `None` in Python) values.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer user10938362.  If you could post that as an answer rather than a comment I can accept it.

Comment: `if number:` is bad practice since it will result in your function returning `None` when `number` is `0` (zeros evaluate as false in boolean context). The proper check is `if number is not None:`.

Answer (score 1):

If there are `NULL` values in the column, PySpark passes `None` for such values and your `round()` function doesn't handle `None`. Something like the following should do:

```
@udf(returnType=DecimalType())
def round_half_even(number):
  return round(number, 0) if number is not None else None
```

Note the proper check for non-`None` values is `var is not None`. Integer and floating-point zeros evaluate to false in boolean context.

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter 'number' may be None, just put a check before calling the round method.

PS: All Python builtin functions are available inside PySpark UDF. If you want to call any other method/library, you'll have to import it inside UDF.